# What is the Process to have an Extension Enhanced?

Tags: extension

I use some Extensions (e.g. Twilio : org.civicrm.sms.twilio).

I would like some enhancements (e.g. : have a specific associated permission or connexion to an existing permission)

What is the best process to get that ?

(I am not a developer, nor familiar with development environment)

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to be a developer to contribute to enhancements -> you could sponsor the work and let an experienced developer do it for you. For org.civicrm.sms.twilio -> go through the Paid Issue Queue: https://civicrm.org/paid-issue-queue The CiviCRM Core team will either be able to work on it - or they will find a CiviCRM partner for you to work with.